# fixed positioned sidebar through a scrollable page

Tags: html, css, css-position, sidebar

I have a sidebar that I would like to have as in the following photo: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtEQt.png)

I want the sidebar to be scrollable, and I also what my entire page to be scrollable (subsequently I can scroll through main area)however I want my sidebar to maintain its position when I scroll the entire page. 
my current css settings are :

```
#sidebar{ 
position: fixed;
top: $height_ofnav
bottom: 0;
width: $sidebarwidth;
margin-left: $main_areawidth;
overflow-y: scroll;
}

#main_area
{
width: $total_screen-sidebarwidth;
}
```

however the behaviour I get when scrolling down my page is :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rg0cu.png)

The behaviour I am trying to implement is similar to the sidebar in https://docs.python.org/3.7/

I think I am missing something,I am not sure even if positioning is the correct way to go, when is float rather used than position fixed?

Comment: If you have a codepen or jsfiddle providing that would help questions get answer quicker.

Comment: If I were to take a crack at it as is I would say that you need to get rid of the top property to or replace it with the height of the header bar.

Comment: @StevenVanSant sorry that is a typo it is supposed to be the height

Comment: I think you need to adjust your question. I think you have other typos and also you really need to put the HTML [Simple minimal case] in order to get a good answer.  Also, your main area, do you mean `calc($total_screen - $sidbarwidth)` or `$total_screen-sidbarwidth` as in you have a css variable named that.

Comment: would you mind provide your `HTML` code so we can try by ourselves.

Comment: here is an app template, that is similar but would need to remix for your needs :) and is also good to learn from. https://github.com/x-tag/basic-app-template

Comment: here is an image of it https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1b6qmhrFYUnf1o1hLCNG5Wx4L5KJ_Ys2-tnykGwetunE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @StevenVanSant I meant a value of calc($total_screen - $sidbarwidth) although I have in it my code as a fixed number,I didn't came across the calc syntax before..sorry for the confusion

Comment: :) => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables MDN docs.